# Hausdorff dimension of closed intervals is not changed under $f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f(x)=x^2$. Prove that for any $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ the dimension of image is not changed i.e $$\dim_HE=\dim_H(f(E))$$

Any set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be represnted as a countable union of closed intervals e.g an open interval can be represented as $E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$. 
So the dimension of $E$ equals to the dimension of the "longest" dimension in the union.

My problem is that I don't know how to prove that the dimension of closed interval is not changed under this function. I could have used $f(x)$ as a Lipschitz function but it gives only a bound. How can I prove it?

Comment: No, not every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be represented as a countable union of closed intervals. Take $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ for example.

Comment: So how can I deal with these sets?

Comment: You don't need to. You're only interested in the dimension, not in the measure, so it's sufficient that the map is locally bi-Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. The locally Lipschitz property gives you that it doesn't increase dimension, and the Lipschitz continuity of the local inverses off $0$ show that it doesn't decrease dimension.

Comment: How it can be bi-Lipschitz if the set cannot be represented as a union of intervals (i.e what will be your bounding $K\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{1}{k}|x_2-x_1|\le|x_2^2-x_1^2|\le K |x_2-x_1|$)? How the local property gives that and how the last fact shows it doesn't decrease?

Comment: Take one step back. $$\dim_H(E) = \inf \{ \alpha > 0 : \mathcal{H}^\alpha(E) = 0\}$$is the definition of the Hausdorff dimension, where $\mathcal{H}^\alpha$ is the $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure. Now use the local Lipschitz-continuity of $f$ to see that if $\mathcal{H}^\alpha(E) = 0$, then $\mathcal{H}^\alpha(f(E\cap [-n,n]))= 0$ for all $n$. That shows a locally Lipschitz map cannot increase Hausdorff dimension. To see that $x\mapsto x^2$ doesn't decrease dimension, use that $y\mapsto \pm \sqrt{y}$ is locally Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: I still cannot understand how the locally continuity implies these facts. sorry for being too tedious and thanks.

Comment: Do you know/can you prove that a globally Lipschitz function maps $\mathcal{H}^\alpha$ null-sets to $\mathcal{H}^\alpha$ null sets? Generally, that it can't increase the measure by more than a factor of $\operatorname{lip}(f)^\alpha$?

Comment: For my shame, not really. Can you supply hints for the proof please?

Comment: If $\{ A_k : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a covering of $E$ by sets of diameter $\leqslant \delta$, then $\{ f(A_k) : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a covering of $f(E)$. What can you say about the diameters of the $f(A_k)$?

Comment: I think that in this case, $diam(f(A_k))\le\delta^2$.

Comment: No. For example $[2,2+\delta]$ is mapped to $[4,4+4\delta+\delta^2]$. And think of the general situation, a Lipschitz-continuous $f$. The concrete example just stands in the way.

Comment: So the diameter is bounded by $b^2-a^2$ for intervals $[a,b]$? if so it gives $|x-y|\le M|f^2-y^2|$ where $M=(b^2-a^2)$?

Comment: Forget the concrete problem for the time being. Understand the principle. Write the definitions of the Hausdorff measure(s) and the Hausdorff dimension on a sheet of paper. Consider an arbitrary metric space $X$. The abstractness helps. Consider a Lipschitz continuous map $f\colon X \to Y$, where $Y$ is another metric space. Understand that (and why) $\mathcal{H}^{\alpha}_Y (f(E)) \leqslant \operatorname{lip}(f)^\alpha\cdot \mathcal{H}^\alpha_X(E)$ for every $E\subset X$. And then understand that hence Lipschitz maps never increase Hausdorff dimension. **Then** look at the concrete problem.

Comment: Just verifying: in$lip(f)^\alpha$ you mean the alpha s.t $|f(x)-f(y)|\le\alpha|x-y|$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is just an exponent there. $$\begin{aligned}\operatorname{lip}(f)\; &:= \sup \left\{ \frac{d_Y(f(x),f(y))}{d_X(x,y)} : x,y\in X,\, x \neq y\right\}\\ &= \inf \left\{ C > 0 : \bigl(\forall x,y \in X\bigr)\bigl(d_Y(f(x),f(y)) \leqslant C\cdot d_X(x,y)\bigr)\right\},\end{aligned}$$ where $d_X,\,d_Y$ are the metrics on $X$ resp. $Y$.